# Why does my Retopology have these shade edges?

Tags: subdivision-surface, topology

I was creating some clothing by doing topology on a body. I then subdivided the object to make it higher poly, and then these weird shade edges appeared. Does anyone know why it appeared and how to avoid it?

[image]

Comment: Maybe inverted normals? Switch to Edit mode, select all and press Shift N?

Comment: That was it! Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

This is inverted normals:

- Press <kbd>tab</kbd> to switch to *Edit Mode*
- Press <kbd>A</kbd> to select all faces
- Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> to recalculate normals